# Conway's Game of Life in Python - Competitive Programming - how to optimize

Tags: python, numpy, performance, optimization, conways-game-of-life

I am solving [Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) problem on [csacademy](https://csacademy.com/ieeextreme-practice/task/d12a7784af1a3d3f6d88601c81a4bb81/) and I can't manage to beat the time on larger inputs. Any help on optimizing the code?

I tried changing things, like using np.array() instead of list, and not converting the original input to 1s and 0s (original is '*' and '-', and needs to be printed that way).

```
from copy import deepcopy
import numpy as np
aliveToDead = {0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
deadToAlive = {3}


def countNeighbors(M, n, m, i, j):
    s = M[i, (j + 1) % m] + M[i, j - 1] + M[(i + 1) % n, j] + M[i - 1, j]
    s += M[i - 1, j - 1] + M[(i + 1) % n, (j + 1) % m] + M[i - 1, (j + 1) % m] + M[(i + 1) % n, j - 1]
    return s


def gameOfLife(mat, n, m, C):
    cells = deepcopy(mat)
    for c in range(C):
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(m):
                neighbors = countNeighbors(mat, n, m, i, j)
                if mat[i, j] == 1 and neighbors in aliveToDead:
                    cells[i, j] = 0
                elif mat[i, j] == 0 and neighbors in deadToAlive:
                    cells[i, j] = 1
        mat = deepcopy(cells)
    return mat


def buildList(n):
    return np.array([[0 if x == '-' else 1 for x in input()] for i in range(n)])


def printResult(mat):
    mat = mat.astype(str)
    mat[mat == "1"] = '*'
    mat[mat == "0"] = '-'
    for row in mat:
        print(*row, sep="")


def main():
    n, m, c = map(int, input().split())
    mat = buildList(n)
    result = gameOfLife(mat, n,  m, c)
    printResult(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: [1] [csacademy](https://csacademy.com/ieeextreme-practice/task/d12a7784af1a3d3f6d88601c81a4bb81/), 
[2] [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life)

Comment: you need to vectorize your code using numpy functions so to be faster. This means removing loops, using `np.where` instead of conditional in loops, working on many 2D arrays. You can perform a convolution to count the neighbors. Using a `np.uint8` dtype help to remove the memory footprint too (and can thus improve performance).

Comment: @JérômeRichard Do you have an idea on how to vectorize it? I can't figure it out

Comment: Well, the previous comment gave the general idea. Note that for the convolution you can use `scipy.signal.convolve2d`. Note also the the Numpy tutorial on the Numpy website/documentation are pretty good to understand how to vectorize codes.

Answer (score 0):

This mathematical solution seems to help pass more tests, but there are still a few that fail.

```
def gameOfLife(mat, n, m, C):
    cells = deepcopy(mat)
    loop = n*m*4*3*5
    while loop % 16:
        loop *= 2
    num_iter = C % loop
    for c in range(num_iter):
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(m):
                neighbors = countNeighbors(mat, n, m, i, j)
                if mat[i, j] == 1:
                    cells[i, j] = aliveToDead[neighbors]
                else:
                    if neighbors==3:
                        cells[i, j] = 1
                    else:
                        cells[i, j] = 0
        mat,cells = cells,mat
    return mat
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.

Comment: @AzharKhan I don't know why this solves the problem, but hopefully in the future someone will see it,  be able to understand it, and post a full answer.